# How to track the order of button presses?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

EDIT: 
Guys, you are so awesome, thanks for all the replies.
I've decided to go the stringByAppendingString route because it seems to be the easiest, but still it won't work for some reason! Please excuse me again if this is way too noobish.
Thanks a lot for all the support!

Here is the piece of code:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    @interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupGame];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
  int finalorder = 12;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed: (UIButton*) button {
    if (button.tag == 1)
    {
        int order = 1;
    }
     if (button.tag == 2)
    {
        [order stringByAppendingString:@"2"];
    }
    if ([order isEqualToString:finalorder])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong!"
                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Try again!"]
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Try"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
                              };

    }
```

// Original quesiton:
I'm very sorry as I'm a complete noob and this is a noob question.

I'm making my first iPhone app, and I want it to be a scale trainer - for people learning musical scales.
There's one octave of piano (12 buttons, one for each key) on the screen, and I want the program to track the order in which the user presses the buttons, in order to learn if he does remember the order of keys in a particular scale.
For example we're in scale C, the keys there are: C, D, E, F, G, A, B.
If the user presses C, and then D, it works further.
But if the user presses C, and then C#, there should be an alert saying: "Wrong! Try again".

Besides that, I want the name of each key to be viewed in a label: if the user presses C key, there is a C and so on.

*So how do I track the order of pressings?*
I've made the next piece of code so far, which shows the name of the key and uses timer.
Thanks a lot for your help!

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupGame];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed: (UIButton*) button {

    if (button.tag == 1)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"C";
    }
    else
    {
    [timer invalidate];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong!"
                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Try again!"]
                delegate:self
                cancelButtonTitle:@"Try"
                otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    }
    if (button.tag == 2)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"C#";
    }

    if (button.tag == 3)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"D";
    }


    if (button.tag == 4)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"D#";
    }

    if (button.tag == 5)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"E";
    }

    if (button.tag == 6)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"F";
    }

    if (button.tag == 7)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"F#";
    }

    if (button.tag == 8)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"G";
    }

    if (button.tag == 9)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"G#";
    }

    if (button.tag == 10)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"A";
    }

    if (button.tag == 11)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"A#";
    }

    if (button.tag == 12)
    {
        waitinglabel.text = @"B";
    }
}

- (void)setupGame {
    seconds = 30;
    count = 0;

    timerlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i", seconds];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(subtractTime)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)subtractTime {
    seconds--;
    timerlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i",seconds];

    if (seconds == 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Mark the answer that helped you as accepted. Also, it's generally not ok to change your question into a new follow-up question.

Comment: I'm ever so sorry!  Will definitely follow the rules next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to make `NSString` of your button press event.

Like you have `finalOrder` is **ABCD** then

```
NSString *order;

1stButtonPress -> order=@"A";
2ndButtonPress -> [order stringByAppendingString:@"B"];
3rdButtonPress -> [order stringByAppendingString:@"C"];
4thButtonPress -> [order stringByAppendingString:@"D"];
```

Not match this

```
if ([order isEqualToString:finalOrder])
    {
        //Your Work
    }
    else{
        //invalid format
    }
```

**EDIT**

According to your question replace `int` with `NSString` i.e.

```
NSString *finalorder = @12";  
NSString *order = @"1";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I decided to this way, but still can't work it out.. Please take a look at the edited question above. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you be so kind to comment a little more detailed about what construction you do mean by "1stButtonPress"? Maybe some example of what you'd write there. Sorry if this is too noobish and many many thanks in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a NSMutableArray and each time a button is pressed, just add the button's tag to the array.

```
[yourArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:button.tag]];
```

In your .h file define this:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *buttonTapArray;
```

in your `setUpGame` do this:

```
self.buttonTapArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and then in your `buttonPress` function just add the first snippet

```
[self.buttonTapArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:button.tag]];
```

to reset the order, just reinitialize the array by doing another

```
self.buttonTapArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Isn't it `[yourArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", button.tag]];` or `[yourArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:button.tag]];` the right way? Since integer isn't object.

Comment: Thanks @h4cky for pointing this out. Of course you're right :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a predefined set of musical notes. You need to first create a unique notation for each note. Create a array of all notes.

Each note will have following info

```
[
  {
    "Tag":1,
    "Name":"C",
    "Info":{}
  },
  {
    "Tag":2,
    "Name":"C#",
    "Info":{}
  }
]
```

By creating an array like this you can remove tag comparison in your buttonPressed: method. You need to assign the tag of the note to the respective button. When a button is pressed using the tag of the button you can find out which note was pressed.

Then you can form the valid order in which a scale is formed using these notes.

Scale C = [1,3,5,6,8,10,12];

You need to keep an instance variable which will keep the track of which note user has entered, each time a button is pressed you would increment it. Upon each event using this index check the tags of notes stored in scale array. If there is a mismatch give an alert.

Answer (score 1):

For examine a sequence of presses you can use:

create class variable:

```
NSMutableArray *_requiredSequence = [@[@"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"A", @"B" ] mutableCopy];
```

And then:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed: (UIButton*) button {
    NSString *pressedNote = [self noteNameForButtonWithTag:button.tag];
    NSString *requiredNote = _requiredSequence[0];

    if ([pressedNote caseInsensitiveCompare:requiredNote] == NSOrderedSame]) {
        waitinglabel.text = pressedNote;  
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        if ([array count] == 0) {
            //finish
        }  
    } else {
        //show alert
    }
}

- (NSString *)noteNameForButtonWithTag:(NSUInteger)tag {
    static NSArray *noteNames = @[@"C", @"C#", @"D", @"D#", ....];
    NSUInteger index = tag - 1;
    return scaleNames[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with using an [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) to store the sequence of scales pressed. Use stringByAppendingString method to add to a sequence, and rangeOfString to check if the pressed sequence is a subset of the correct order of scales

Comment: Thanks a lot! I decided to this way, but still can't work it out.. Please take a look at the edited question above. Thanks!